# Trying to associate xib with KeyboardViewController.swift file in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Sorry guys, new to Xcode

I wanted to make a keyboard that has a picker view that lets you select text and populate a field. I have a KeyboardViewController and a xib file with the PickerView in it. But everytime I launch all I see is a blank keyboard when I try it in simulator, I even tried using spotlight and not the container app.

I'm clearly clueless about something.

My filenames are Len-keyboard_take2.xib and KeyboardViewController.swift.

Comment: How are you initializing KeyboardViewController?